# Order DATETIME only until minute mark (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to order the results from a table first by Target_Time and then by Classification in case of them having the same Target_Time.
Although, I want to order the Target_Time's only until the minute mark, and ignore the seconds. How can I do this?

I want something similiar to this but I know there is something missing in the ORDER BY statement.

```
SELECT * FROM Waiting_List ORDER BY Target_Time, Classification
```

Comment: Can you show some data example and how it should be ordered?

Comment: What's the difference between ordering by the minute and ordering by the entire value?

Comment: For example:

Patient1
Target_Time:22:27
Classification:2;  

Patient2
Target_Time:22:27
Classification:1;  

Patient3
Target_Time:23:00
Classification:1;  

Ordering: Patient2, Patient1, Patient3

Comment: If this is a common need, have you considered adding a column to which the seconds are stripped off?

Answer (score 1):

Try following. Its changing the date format to exclude seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM Waiting_List ORDER BY date_format(Target_Time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), Classification
```

Comment: This is likely to be painful on large tables as it involves a per-row calculation.

Answer (score 1):

TEST this:

```
SELECT * FROM Waiting_List 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE( DATE_FORMAT(Target_Time, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i'), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i'), Classification
```

Mysql will truncate seconds when sorting records. Convert date to String and convert back String to date to compare.